# How to make Generic code to dump to the debugger any IEnumerable and process KeyValuePair separately

Tags: c#, templates, generics, ienumerable, debug-window

I want to write to the debugger the content of any collection, either Dictionary. But for Dictionary, I want to identify Key and Value separatly without having to know what is the type of the key or the value.

In the following code, can I replace "KeyValuePair" with something valid in order to make the code works as expected?

```
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void Dump<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"START: Enumeration of type {typeof(T).Name}");
        foreach (T item in enumerable)
        {
            if (item is KeyValuePair kvp)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key,-20}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Print(item?.ToString() ?? "<empty string>");
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine($"END  : Enumeration of type {typeof(T).Name}");
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just serialize the whole thing (maybe json) and dump that? Smarter people than us have done all the work already...

Answer (score 0):

For the exact scenario you've asked about, the simplest approach is to write a different overload of `Dump` to handle any `IReadOnlyDictionary<K, V>`, so the enumeration item type will be `KeyValuePair<K, V>`.

But as you try to handle more cases, you'll probably want to consider recursive structures, e.g. dictionaries of lists of dictionaries, in which case your `Dump` method will need to become recursive and be able to accept any `object`, so it can dispatch to the right formatting code at runtime, not being at all dependent on knowing types at compile time. That's a different question though!

Comment: I wan tto write only one function. The way you propose, I will also have to write one for dictionary which is what I want to avoid.